# Unable to Recreate NullReferenceException Error

Tags: vb.net

So, I'm running into a NullReferenceException error in my code.

```
CreatureNumber = CreatureNumberLabel.Text
If YouOrEnemyCreatureLabel.Text = "You" Then
Person = "Your"
End If
If YouOrEnemyCreatureLabel.Text = "Enemy" Then
Person = "Enemy"
End If

'The line below is giving me the error. "_" Added for convenience.
Simulator.Controls(Person & "Creature" & CreatureNumber & "NameLabel").Text = _
   CreatureNameComboBox.Text
```

Person and CreatureNumber have both been declared publicly, and I had to put "Simulator" in front since that's the userform that contains the control that I want to change the text of.

Now, the problem is that when I tried to recreate this issue (using 2 different userforms), it worked just how I intended it to.

```
Number = TextBox1.Text
Form2.Controls("Label" & Number).Text = TextBox2.Text
```

Again, Number was declared publicly. So why is the above code working just fine, but the first one is giving me a NullReferenceException error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question ^~^

Turns out, the control that I was trying to edit was in a Panel in the first example (the one that was giving me the error), but not in the second.
So the fix was simply to change this:

```
Simulator.Controls(Person & "Creature" & CreatureNumber & "NameLabel").Text =_
   CreatureNameComboBox.Text
```

To this:

```
Simulator.Panel1.Controls(Person & "Creature" & CreatureNumber & "NameLabel").Text = _
   CreatureNameComboBox.Text
```